# Compiling Filesystem in USErspace in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, fuse

My english is not the best so i'am sorry of that. I want to build my own filesystem using fuse. Is it possible to do this project in Eclipse? I have some problems when try to do it. I've added `pkg-config fuse --cflags --libs` to "Compiler invocation arguments" but it didn't help. 
Please help,
Cris

Answer (score 0):

I didn't write my project in Eclipse, but i found useful way to debug projects in fuse. For details see above link:

http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/classes/hmc.cs135.201001/homework/fuse/fuse_doc.html#compiling

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings* and try adding `` `pkg-config fuse --cflags` `` to the "*Other flags*" edit box in the *GCC C++ Compiler* as well as the *GCC C Compiler*  *Miscellaneous*. Make sure not to forget the ` backticks!

In the Linker Miscellanous section you should then add `` `pkg-config fuse --libs` ``.

I didn't try this but I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project's **Properties** and go to **C/C++ Build** → **Settings** → **Tool settings**.  Make sure that the **Configuration** is set to `[ All configurations ]`.  Now go to **GCC C Compiler** → **Miscellaneous** and add `` `pkg-config fuse --cflags` `` to the **Other flags** field then hit **Apply**.  Next go to **GCC C Linker** and add `` `pkg-config fuse --libs` `` to the end of **Command line pattern** (under **Expert settings**) then click on **Apply and close**.  Your FUSE project should now compile without errors.